# Thymeleaf Controller Not Rendering

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

UPDATE: Switched the annotation from @RestController to @Controller and now I simply get a 404 when trying to hit http://localhost:8080/api/v1/create_short_url. I added a System.out.println into the controller and see it being printed, so I know it's making it into the controller. I think it just can't find the template.

```
@Controller 
@RequestMapping("/api/v1") 
public class UrlShorteningController {

    @GetMapping("/create_short_url")
public String newShortUrl(Model model) {
    System.out.println("^^^^^^^");
    model.addAttribute("longUrl",
        new String());
    return "new-short-url-form";
}
```

Request 
[image]

---

I have the a controller which I expect to render an HTML template. Instead, it just returns the name of the controller. What am I doing wrong here?

**Actual**:
[image: Actual]

**Expected**:
Rendering of the html page

#### Code

[image]

Controller in src/main/java/com/example/urlshortener/api/UrlShorteningController.java:

```
@RestController
....
@GetMapping("/create_short_url")
public String newShortUrl(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("longUrl",
        new String());
    return "new-short-url-form";
}
```

build.gradle:

```
... 
dependencies {
...
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
...
}
```

Thymeleaf Template in src/main/resources/templates/new-short-url-form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>New Short Url</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/create_short_url_thymeleaf}" th:object="${String}">
    <h1>Enter a url to shorten</h1>
    <input type="text" id="longUrl" th:field="*{String}"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Thymeleaf Template in src/resources/templates/new-short-url-form.html

The path for templates should be src/**main**/resources/templates/

Comment: Good catch! Unfortunately moving it there didn't seem to help :/ Same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I realized my editor wasn't picking up the view name. I have no idea, why, as the folder structure seemed correct. I tried renaming it to "some-form" and it suddenly works. Not sure if there is a length restriction on html file names top be picked up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're using a `GetMapping` instead of a `RequestMapping`. Use `RequestMapping` if you expect to provide a template. `GetMapping` is only for a get request which explains why you're receiving the literal String and not the template.

Comment: I've also done this successfully with a get mapping in the past - https://github.com/ericadohring/greetings/commit/d0626ecac2351bfebd7071657082b80232966b3d. If you pull that repo, checkout that commit, and run it, it'll stand up and return a similar template.

Comment: thats wrong, the @GetMapping Annotation is only a shortcut for `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)`, show [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html)

Comment: If you stand up that app with that commit sha, it works.

Comment: You need to replace @RestController and use a RequestMapping.

Comment: The combination of RestController and RequestMapping OR GetMapping returns the string of the form name (like I have in the original question). Controller with RequestMapping OR GetMapping returns a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ModelAndView

```
@Controller 
@RequestMapping("/api/v1") 
public class UrlShorteningController {

    @GetMapping("/create_short_url")
public ModelAndView newShortUrl() {
 ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    System.out.println("^^^^^^^");
modelAndView.addObject("longUrl",
        new String());
modelAndView.setViewName("new-short-url-form")
return modelAndView;
}
```

And replace your `html` tag with `<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">`